# How do you test for a jumped timing chain on a 2005 malibu classic 2.2 engine

Tags: starting, chevrolet, malibu-classic

4 door sedan malibu classic 2.2 engine. 
Yes I meant jumped timing chain. How come I think that . . . 
Because I scanned with an OBD scanner got the PO455 code and the PO141 code. Emission control valve ( large leak ) and O2 sensor bank 1 O2 rear sensor. I replaced them. Went to start the car and it would not start. There is gas and there is spark ( here weak spark ). I don't know what else to think. I cleared the codes and ran another scan and it comes back clear. No problems. I am not used to these new things in these cars. All these senors and cheap have done nothing but screw up our cars. I am in my mid- 60's and we didn't have all this cap. Yes I am very frustrated.
How do I test for jumped timing chain ? If it is that. If not what can it be ? I am having surgery done at the VA hospital May 2nd and need this car to get me there or I am screwed?

Comment: you mean stretched timing chain?

Comment: Welcome to the site, Steve. Unfortunately, your question doesn't make a lot of sense. Using the [edit] feature, can you share with us what problem you are having and why you want to check the timing chain (did you mean "jumped")? How many miles are on the engine? You tagged [starting], is that a problem?

Answer (score 2):

I would start by turning the crankshaft to the TDC (Top Dead Centre) position for cylinder 1 and then checking the alignment of the other shafts as specified for that engine.

Comment: Just some info on the gm 2.2. It has a tdc mark on the timing cover and balancer but no correlating marks on the cam gears. They do have a diamond shaped hole that should be roughly 35 degrees from the top and pointing away from each other at tdc. There are also colored links on the chain but good luck lining them all up. The best way to verify stretch is to compare ckp/cmp waveform vs known good. the chain guides tend to break (plastic- lack of service) before the chain stretches and when they do break its pretty noisy.

Comment: Some engines for the initial build when the elrctronics are not available or working at that point require the use of a dial gauge to locate the point of maximum lift,or the lowest, to set the timing. This is also the case when using the adjustable gear wheels when adjusting the timing. Had to do this on some diesels - as 0.5 of a degree can in some engines cause lots of smoke...

Answer (score 1):

the simplest thing you can do is a compression check. If the chain is failed you will have zero  (You'd probably know that already as the engine will crank way too easy ).  If it has "jumped" the compression will be low ( of course it could be low for other reasons.)